# Почему при добавлении кода перестает работать ajax запрос?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Ajax запрос успешно получает ответ от сервлета, если сервлет содержит только одну строчку - `response.getWriter().print("test");`. Почему при попытке настроить содержимое `response` или при попытке закрыть поток ответ не проходит и срабатывает обработчик ошибки `error` с одинаковым статусом(результат `console.log(jqXHR)` = `Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}`)?(На самом деле ответ не проходит при попытке добавить любой код, кроме указанной строчки, всегда статус ошибки одинаковый.)

Код запроса

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-button").click(function () {
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {login: userLogin, password: userPassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Successful request! Data is " + data.toString());
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Код сервлета

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //При попытке добавить этот код
    /*response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");*/

    response.getWriter().print("text");

    //Или этот код ответ уже не проходит
    /*response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();*/

}
```

Comment: Возможно имеет смысл обработать исключения, а не выкидывать их.

Comment: Обработал, исключений при работе не возникает

Comment: В логи что-нибудь попадает?

Comment: К сожалению, вообще ничего, хоть я и ловлю самую общую ошибку `catch(Exception ex)`